# Is it a good idea to perform FragmentTransactions inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, fragmenttransaction

As the title suggest, is it a good idea to perform `FragmentTransaction` inside a fragment?

The way I view this is that, `FragmentTransaction` requires a containerView id and the Fragment to inflate when calling `FragmentTransaction.replace()`. The containerView where to get the ID usually resides in the activity layout. So it seems like a good idea to do `FragmentTransaction` inside the activity rather than in the Fragment.

But I got confused when using `SharedElementTransition` for fragments. Now it requires a list of `Views` which will be the sharedElements. These views reside in the Fragment. Now it seems logical to do the FragmentTransaction inside the Fragment itself.

Can anyone guide me on how to compensate for both scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong on doing `FragmentTransaction` inside a `fragment` as long as it is not redundant, like for example:

"Container" Fragment

"Child Fragment" that holds view pager

View pager has fragments

Here, you can remove the child fragment and hold the view pager on container fragment instead.

For `FragmentTransaction` inside a `fragment`, you can actually swap the `fragment` itself by calling `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`. Here, transaction is happening on `Activity` not on the `fragment`. But if you intended to use `FragmentTransaction` to swap the child of the parent `fragment`, you can use `getChildFragmentManager()` on the `fragment`.

Also, **child fragments** is actually supported by [android](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2#NestedFragments).